# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray doesn't keep color information when pixel is fully transparent

Tags: android

I use the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray to generate a Bitmap from a PNG image. Then I use Bitmap.getPixels to retrive all the pixel data. The problem is that when a pixel is set as fully transparent, all the color data seams to be discarded. 0x0000ff00 is being returned as 0x00000000. If I create an image from code which has transparent pixels I make a copy, render that to a canvas, use Canvas.drawColor(0xff000000, Mode.DST_ATOP) and then get all the correct color values with getPixels and then add that with the alpha values I got from the first getPixels call. I can't do that now since the color information seams to be gone.
Is there any way to make sure that the color information is stored when generating a Bitmap from a PNG file using the BitmapFactory?

Answer (score 0):

try setting BitmapFactory.Options.inDither = false, it should do the trick. 
Took the wisdom from [here.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8b1abdbe881f9f71)

Comment: Thanks Axarydax, but it didn't help. The color values for fully transparent pixels are still incorrect. 0x00ffffff becomes 0x00000000. I will try to find another work around.